# Ignoring certain variables in a jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, steam

There's a javascript code in the steam blotter page ( the page with activity and other stuff ) and javascript:

```
(function() { 
    jQuery(".btn_grey_grey.btn_small_thin.ico_hover").map(function(){
        this.click()
    });
})().
```

I want it to ignore "btn_grey_grey.btn_small_thin.ico_hover.active" and only click on btn_grey_grey.btn_small_thin.ico_hover. Is it possible to do that? The current code clicks on the active ones and inactive buttons. Double quotes doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Use the `:not()` selector

Comment: Why are you using map() to loop and click?

Comment: Sorry I only just started to learn JavaScript last week, I am not very good at it yet. I will do better in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not` selector and `each` instead of `map` (it's used for different purposes):

```
jQuery(".btn_grey_grey.btn_small_thin.ico_hover:not(.active)").each(function() {
    this.click();
});
```

Note also that if you bind event handlers with jQuery you can try simpler expression:

```
jQuery(".btn_grey_grey.btn_small_thin.ico_hover:not(.active)").click();
```